# Magento 2 Save custom customer attribute to customer addresses in checkout

Tags: magento2, checkout, customer-attribute

There are many post on Stackexchange and blogs that explain how to add custom field to checkout forms. Some of them also explain how to save them to **quote/order address**.

I've achieved all these results, but I'm still not able to save my custom customer attribute to customer address in checkout neither guest nor registered customers. And what about if the shipping and billing address are different?

Does anyone know if there is a "**definitive**" guide on how to save custom customer attributes to customer address, or give me a piece of advice about the way to do it?

Thanks

Comment: Did you get a solution to this problem? I am dealing with something similar and I cannot get to save the custom attribute to the customer address Thanks in advance

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/156388)

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/156388)